# SQL inner join creates duplicates

Tags: sql, inner-join

I have three tables, Suppliers, Products and Deliveries. I'd like to show the suppliers names and the quantity from the delivery table. There are 5 different suppliers and there are 12 deliveries. I expect that the joined table should contain 12 rows with names and deliveries.

This is my code.

```
SELECT  Suppliers.SNAME, Deliveries.QTY
FROM Suppliers, Deliveries
INNER JOIN  Products
ON Deliveries.P=Products.Penter (typo, should be Products.P)
```

The output is 60 rows with many duplicates and some incorrect matches.

Tables:
[image: Suppliers]
[image: Products]
[image: Deliveries]

Comment: 5x12 = 60, sounds like your `JOIN` could use additional criteria.  Post table structure/sample data and we can nail it.

Comment: You need to specify the `JOIN` condition betweeen the Suppliers and the other two tables.

Comment: I think you must define a join between suppliers and deliveries too. Since you cross joined them in your example

Comment: use `group by` and that would solved the issue

Comment: You are mixing implict joins (in the where clause) and explicit joins using `JOIN` keyword. Don't do that.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Kill off deprecated implicit joins, and specify `JOIN` criteria, not sure of your table structures, something like:

```
SELECT  s.SNAME, d.QTY
FROM Deliveries d
INNER JOIN Suppliers s
 ON d.s = s.s
INNER JOIN  Products p
 ON d.p = p.p
```

An unspecified implicit `JOIN` ie:

```
SELECT  Suppliers.SNAME, Deliveries.QTY
FROM Suppliers, Deliveries
```

Will result in every record from each table joining to every record in the other, in your case, 5 records and 12 records = 60 combinations.

Comment: `Suppliers` alias `p` should be `s`. Would fix myself but there is a minimum of 6 character edits.

Answer (score 3):

Use proper join syntax consistently.  You are mixing old-style joins (`,` with condition in the `where` clause) with proper ANSI `join` syntax.

You mean something like this:

```
SELECT s.SNAME, d.QTY
FROM Suppliers s join
     Deliveries d
     d.SupplierId = s.SupplierId join
     Products p
     ON d.P = Products.Penter;
```

I'm making up the join field between `Suppliers` and `Deliveries`.  And, I'm only guessing that those are the tables that need to be connected (perhaps it is `Suppiers` and `Products`).